Compiling Z3 from source with CMake
I'm attempting to build Z3 from source using CMake. As far as I understand from the instructions in the repo, this should be fairly straightforward. I'm building as follows:
ExternalProject_Add(
  z3
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git"
  GIT_TAG z3-4.13.0
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DZ3_BUILD_LIBZ3_SHARED=FALSE)

This all appears to be resolved correctly, but then when it comes to building, I'm getting all manner of compilation errors such as the following:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/core_solver_pretty_printer.cpp:21:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/core_solver_pretty_printer_def.h:24:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/lp_core_solver_base.h:27:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/static_matrix.h:17:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/permutation_matrix.h:29:
/workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/tail_matrix.h:46:53: error: no member named 'get_elem' in 'tail_matrix<T, X>'
   46 |         T operator[](unsigned j) const { return m_A.get_elem(m_row, j);}

In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/core_solver_pretty_printer.cpp:21:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/core_solver_pretty_printer_def.h:24:
In file included from /workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/lp_core_solver_base.h:27:
/workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/static_matrix.h:83:72: error: no member named 'get' in 'static_matrix<T, X>'; did you mean 'set'?
   83 |         ref operator=(ref & v) { m_matrix.set(m_row, m_col, v.m_matrix.get(v.m_row, v.m_col)); return *this; }
      |                                                                        ^~~
      |                                                                        set
/workspace/build/external/z3-prefix/src/z3/src/math/lp/static_matrix.h:166:10: note: 'set' declared here
  166 |     void set(unsigned row, unsigned col, T const & val);

Taking a (admittedly cursory) look at the actual code, I'm at a bit of a loss as to how this could ever compile; I'm unable to see a get method anywhere in the static_matrix class, for instance. Clearly I'm doing something wrong here as I'm sure such an error simply isn't feasible for such a well-regarded library, but I'm kind of scratching my head... Indeed, when I just clone and attempt to build as a standalone library:
$> git clone https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git
$> cd z3 && git checkout tags/z3-4.13.0
$> mkdir build && cd build
$> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -j4 ..
$> make install

I get no problems at all and everything builds successfully.
